# VirtualBox not starting after windows 10 creators update

Tags: vagrant, windows-10, virtualbox

I am using vagrant with virtual box. After the **windows 10 creator update**, the vagrant startup is failing.

```
[# madhukar] vagrant up
Bringing machine 'vpnbox' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> vpnbox: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> vpnbox: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> vpnbox: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> vpnbox: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    vpnbox: Adapter 1: nat
==> vpnbox: Forwarding ports...
    vpnbox: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    vpnbox: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> vpnbox: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "716b386e-6fd3-4100-a576-25ffd53511f4", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'vagrant_vpnbox_1476445010924_89306' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

I tried to start Oracle Virtual Box separately, buts it is also failing. It isn't showing any errors but Virtual Box is not starting up as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Virtual Box (Version 5.1.6) is probably having some compatibility issue with windows-10 update. I updated Virtual box to 5.1.22 and this seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My Virtual box was on version 5.1.6 . I upgraded it to the latest version 5.1.30 available as of today. This fixed the issue. I was able to launch the VMs installed in the virtual box.